# IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to run this command `python run.py --mode MLE`
and got this error. I am not able to find the correct solution for it .

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 208, in <module>
    train_MLE()
  File "run.py", line 94, in train_MLE
    encoder_input, decoder_input, weight = model.get_batch(d_valid, i)
  File "C:\Users\Kriti Gupta\Desktop\GitHub_repo\Seq2seq-Chatbot-With-Deep-Reinforcement-Learning\seq2seq_model.py", line 342, in get_batch
    encoder_input, decoder_input = random.choice(data[bucket_id])
  File "C:\Users\Kriti Gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\random.py", line 261, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

Below is the code which contains the function

```
def get_batch(self, data, bucket_id, rand = True, order = False):
    # data should be [whole_data_length x (source, target)] 
    # decoder_input should contain "GO" symbol and target should contain "EOS" symbol
    encoder_size, decoder_size = self.buckets[bucket_id]
    encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs = [], []
    #print(bucket_id)
    print(random.choice(data[bucket_id]))

    encoder_input, decoder_input = random.choice(data[bucket_id])
    c = 0

    for i in xrange(self.batch_size):
      if rand:
        encoder_input, decoder_input = random.choice(data[bucket_id])
      if order:
        encoder_input, decoder_input = data[bucket_id][i]
        c += 1
```

Please help!!

Comment: Well it seems like your `data[bucket_id]` is empty, so `random.choice()` fails. Nothing else can really be concluded without seeing your code.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the function which contains ```data[bucket_id]```

Comment: This code doesn't show anything about what the data inside `data[bucket_id]` looks like. You should look at what code calls this method. It might also be worth adding debug statements throughout.

Answer (score 1):

random.choice always raises IndexError on an empty sequence. I would suggest checking the data you are passing to the function

> get_batch()

You can also add an 'if condition' in 'get_batch()' method to check if the data passed is empty or not.

Reference:
[Python Bug Tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue33203)